# Deploying PlayFramework 2.5 app to heroku

Tags: git, heroku, playframework

I am following this guide:

https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ProductionHeroku

to deploy app to heroku.

First I tried with sbt-heroku plugin , but heroku is using some old mysql version , because Ebean ORM which is mostly used with play was defining datetime as datatime(6) so i set new column definitions and run again "sbt stage deployHeroku" , hoewer app is not working and I am having exactly same error as I had when I deployed first time. This error is FIXED in my app, but heroku is still someonehow using old version.

So I tried second way with heroku-git. I managed to push my play project to same heroku app, however play framework was not detected. And when I look at logs I still see same error from first deployment......

I spend whole day trying to deploy it to heroku.. such a great developer experience..

Can someone point me to working way???

Answer (score 2):

When you switch from the sbt-heroku plugin to Git deployment, you'll also need to set your buildpack by running:

```
$ heroku buildpacks:set heroku/scala
```

When you say "app is not working and I am having exactly same error as I had when I deployed first time" I assume you mean the code has not been deployed. You can check if this is the case by running `heroku run bash` to inspect what is on Heroku. The source won't be there by default (when using sbt-heroku) but you can check for version numbers in your binaries.

With regard to the MySQL issue, Heroku does not provide MySQL, but a few third-party add-on providers do. If you have a problem with the version, I recommend trying [JawsDB MySQL](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/jawsdb) if you are not already.